# Trouble with insert()

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I'm just starting with Android DBs and have trouble inserting data with the `insert()` function. I have a custom `Class` *StudyCardSet* and when I try to add it to the database, only some of the values seem to be inserted successfully (_*id* and *title*), while *frontid* is null:

MySQLHelper.java:

```
private static final String SET_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCSET + "(" + 
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
        TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
        FRONTID + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

DataSource.java:

```
public StudyCardSet createStudyCardSet(StudyCardSet nStudyCardSet) 
{
        // Set of study cards:  _id |   title   |   frontid 
    Log.d("mydebug", "starting creation of Set: " + nStudyCardSet.getTitle() + ": " + nStudyCardSet.getFrontID());
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.TITLE, nStudyCardSet.getTitle());
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.FRONTID, nStudyCardSet.getFrontID());
    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCSET, null, values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SCSET, allSets, MySQLiteHelper.ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    StudyCardSet newSet = cursorToSet(cursor);
    Log.d("mydebug", String.valueOf(newSet.getId()) + " - newSet: " + newSet.getTitle() + ": " + newSet.getFrontID());
    cursor.close();
    return newSet;
}
```

The first `Log.d` of `createStudyCardSet` shows all three values correctly, but in *newSet*, the frontid seems to be `null`.

I would appreciate some help on what I'm doing wrong, I tried Google and a lot of messing around, but I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Please post `cursorToSet()` and `allSets` projection

Comment: Actually you close the cursor using `cursor.close();` then you are returning the cursor

Comment: @ViswanathL, the code provided returns a StudyCardSet object, not the Cursor.

Comment: @MikeM. did you see this `StudyCardSet newSet = cursorToSet(cursor);`

Comment: @Markstart can you post the method `cursorToSet(cursor)`

Comment: @ViswanathL, yes. Obviously the cursorToSet() method returns a StudyCardSet object, which is what is then returned by the createStudyCardSet() method.

Comment: Darn you guys are fast. :) It was indeed the `cursorToSet()` method which only got the _id and the title. I had totally forgotten about this and never checked it again after writing it initially... @laalto: If you post it as answer I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was indeed the cursorToSet() method which only got the _id and the title. I had totally forgotten about this and never checked it again after writing it initially... @laalto: If you post it as answer I'll mark it as solution.

The `cursorToSet()` should transfer the columns from `allSets` projection to a new `StudyCardSet` object. Based on your comment above a column value was left out in `cursorToSet()`.